# Body tag not engulfing entire page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website and for some reason my body tag doesn't cover the entire page and as such the image that is supposed to be at the bottom of the page is appearing in the middle. I have no idea why this is happening because the body tag is closed at the bottom of the page. The site can be found here http://www.chune.biz/The-Beginning-of-A-Musical-Revolution.html.

Comment: Which image is supposed to be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Please avoid linking to external sites — instead, try to replicate your problem with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `height: 100%` from your body css definition.

Comment: when I remove the height, the footer no longer stays at the bottom of the site. How can I get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page without the height being 100%

Comment: You can set it's position to absolute or fixed depending on what effect you want.  Try `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: This still creates an issue as the pages are inconsistent. For shorter pages the image doesn't move to the footer it stays in the middle. This is on the home page. However on the original page the image goes to the bottom but the footer stays high up on the page.

Comment: Well you'll probably need to remedy with some javascript then. Grab the height of the viewport like so:  `windowHeight = window.innerHeight;` and then set the body height to that amount.  Or offset the footer that amount from the top of the page.